# How to change api_token parameter to some custom parameter like api_key or key

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-authentication, laravel-api

I have a Laravel application using API token authentication. By default, the user needs to pass the `api_token` parameter as part of the URL, but I want to change `api_token` to a custom name parameter like `api_key`.

Currently the full URL looks like:

https://www.example.com/api/v2/?api_token=something&action=balance

however I want it to look like following:

https://www.example.com/api/v2?api_key=something&action=balance

OR

https://www.example.com/api/v2?key=something&action=balance

My API routes are using a middleware called `auth:api`, but I am unable to find this middleware to try and change its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done it, but I believe that the `auth.guards.api.input_key` settings will allow you to specify it. So your `auth.php` would look partly like this:

```php
<?php

return [
    "guards" => [
        "api" => [
            "driver" => "token",
            "provider" => "users",         // the database table
            "storage_key" => "api_token",  // the database column
            "input_key" => "api_key",      // the query string component
            "hash" => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create your own middleware

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $token = request('key'); //it can be anything 
    if ($token != 'abc') { // this value can be static or can be get from database
        return response([
            'error' => 2,
            'message' => ["Access Denied"]
        ]);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

here you can match with token and allow them certain request

> **NOTE**: it will work on url paramter not headers token for header you need to get token from header